# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when accessing sharepoint 2013 REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

The REST API ("`/_api`" and "`/_vti_bin/client.svc`") doesn't work with anonymous access in 2013.

Getting `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`  when accessing the above Sharepoint REST API.

```
stack trace : "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.\"}}}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the REST services are only working for authenticated users.
 The REST API ("/_api" and "/_vti_bin/client.svc") doesn't work with anonymous access in 2013.

[SharePoint 2013 APIs for anonymous and/or mobile access](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47156/sharepoint-2013-apis-for-anonymous-and-or-mobile-access)

[SharePoint 2013 and anonymous access problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/sharepoint-2013-and-anonymous-access-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use Digest in the header. if you are using _api call

Comment: Can you please add more information, some examples of code will help other readers.